# Mongoose Populate - Retornar dados especificos

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Estou usando o populate para retornar dados do usuario que criou uma postagem. Funciona bem, o problema é que o populate retorna o usuario inteiro, incluindo hash de senha e outras informações, mas eu só preciso do nome e imagem, então crio um novo objeto apenas com essas duas informações, coloco na postagem e dou como resposta da API o novo dado formatado.

Eu sei que tem uma forma mais direta de fazer isso, mas não lembro, que é usar o populate ou outro metodo para retorna apenas os dados especificos da minha referencia. Qual as chaves que uso?

**Model/Schema da postagem:**

```
const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: 'users', required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true, min: 3, max: 100 },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    creationDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true, min: 3, max: 150 },
})
```

**Buscando a postagem junto com os dados do seu criador:**

```
const post = await posts.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate('author')
```

**A saida dessa forma fica parecido com:**

```
post: {
    title: 'novo post',
    body: 'apenas um teste',
    creationDate: '2021-05-31',
    slug: 'novo-post',
    author: {
        name: 'teste',
        email: 'teste@gmail.com',
        image: 'asdf',
        hash: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
        ...
    }
```

Depois eu pego só as informações que preciso, mas gostaria de receber diretamente do mongoose os dados especificos do author.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método populate com select:

```
const post = await posts.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate({path: 'author', select: 'name email image'})
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Existe diferentes formas para solucionar este tipo de problema, uma delas é a respoatas dada acima pelo **Sinuhe Djin Maschio Shin**. Utlizando **path** e o **select** deste modo poderá obter do **author** apenas os campos que deseja:

```
const post = await posts.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate({ path: 'author', select: 'email' })
```

Podemos melhorar o código aplicando desestruturação:

```
const { slug } = req.params
const post = await posts.findOne({ slug }).populate({ path: 'author', select: 'email' })
```

Para mais informações sobre a utilização do populate basta acessa o link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Também podes manter o método que está usando: `const post = await posts.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate('author')`, para acessar os campos desejados basta escrever `post.author.email` para retornar o email ou qualquer outro campo do **author** que desejar obter.